# When will the EU Unified Patent Court come into existence?

Tags: european, unitary-patents, inified-patent-court

So far I have gathered that one can apply for an [Unitary Patents(UP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_patent) when the [Unified Patent Court (UPC)](http://www.unified-patent-court.org) comes into existences. This will come into existence when:

- **either** on the first day of the 4th month after the deposit of the 13th instrument of ratification or accession (whereby France, Germany and the United Kingdom must be included among these 13 states),
- **or** on the first day of the 4th month after the date of entry into force of the amendments to *Regulation (EC) 1215/2012 (Regulation (EU) No 1215/2012 of the European Parliament and of the Council of 20.12.2012 on jurisdiction and the recognition and enforcement of judgments in civil and commercial matters (OJEU L351/1 of  20.12.2010), including any subsequent amendments)* concerning its relationship with this Agreement

Well I would like to file for such a patent yet information is scarce. So far I found:

- [This document on the site of the UPC](http://www.unified-patent-court.org/images/documents/roadmap-201409.pdf) saying the court won't be here in 2015
- [This site showing the number of states that have ratified this court](http://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/documents-publications/agreements-conventions/agreement/?aid=2013001)

My question is, what does it all mean and when can I file for such a patent?